# change color of SOM patch faces and text in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, colors, matlab-figure, som

I'm graphing a 20 x 20 SOM using the plotsomhits() function. A plot is automatically generated with white text (the number of input vectors in that neuron), overlaid on a blue patch (where the size of the patch corresponds to the number of observations/ input vectors in that neuron) on top of grid with a white background (representing the neurons). For the cells/neurons with small number of observations/input vectors the white text blends into the white cell background and is unreadable. I found a way to manually change each "patch" one by one using the figure GUI (View=>Property Editor=>*click on each cell individually*) but I would have to do that 400 times for this particular plot. Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to change all of the text in all of the patches to be black so that the numbers are readable? Thanks you!

[Picture_of_my_SOM.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jhdv.png)

```
input1=randi([0 1], 50000, true);
input2=randi([0 1], 50000, true);
input3=randi([0 1], 50000, true);
input4=randi([0 100], 50000, true);
fakedata = [input1, input2, input3, input4];
D = 20;
dimensions = [D D];
coverSteps = 30;
initNeighbor = 3;
topologyFcn = 'gridtop';
distanceFcn = 'linkdist';
net1 = selforgmap(dimensions, coverSteps, initNeighbor, topologyFcn,distanceFcn);
net1 = train(net1, fakedata');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by getting all the [child objects of the current axes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-Children), selecting only the text objects using [`findobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html), and setting all of their colors in one step like so:

```
set(findobj(get(gca, 'Children'), 'Type', 'Text'), 'Color', 'k');
```

Here's an example, using the Fisher Iris data set:

```
x = iris_dataset;
net = selforgmap([5 5]);
net = train(net, x);
plotsomhits(net, x);
set(findobj(get(gca, 'Children'), 'Type', 'Text'), 'Color', 'k');
```

And you should get a plot similar to this:

[image]

If you'd also like to change the colors of the hexagonal patch objects (either the blue foreground or white background), you can get a vector of all the patch object handles, select either the first half (foreground patches) or last half (background patches), and set the [`FaceColor` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.patch-properties.html#buduav0-1_sep_shared-FaceColor) to a given color value:

```
patches = findobj(get(gca, 'Children'), 'Type', 'Patch');  % All the patch objects
set(patches(1:25), 'FaceColor', 'r');   % Make foreground patches red
set(patches(26:50), 'FaceColor', 'c');  % Make background patches cyan
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Is there a way to change the patch face color as well? It doesn't show it as having any color properties to change. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jane: I added a bit at the end explaining how to modify the patch objects.